# Is it possible to clear an Android application RAM content when the user logs off/closes the app?

Tags: android

As an example, take an Android app that manages sensitive information such as credit card details. Is it possible from a code level to effectively erase the sensitive data the app might store in RAM when the user logs off or closes the application? How can this be done?

Comment: use onPause/onDestroy methods to do that manually. You can set variables to null, and call GC

Comment: This is error prone. User can always decide to kill your app ungracefully. I don't think even https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application#onTerminate() (of application) is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: What is your definition of "erased"? Zeroed in physical memory? Or garbage collected?

Answer (score 1):

Your can do something like that in your Developer Settings
**How to unlock developer settings?**
You can unlock your developer settings by going to: *Settings > About phone > Software info > Build number.*, Remember that the names of the folders can be different depending on your brand/model of your phone. Once you've reaced *Build number*, click it about 7 times. After a while you should get a toast message saying how many clicks left. Keep clicking until it says you've finished all the clicks. *CONGRATS! Your have unlocked delevopers mode*
Now that you have unlocked your developer settings, scroll right down to the bottom. A little bit to the top you should have a categorie about apps. There you find: *Don't keep activities*, when you turn that on, instead of closing the app a normal way, every app is forced to shut down. I know it's not the same as clearing everything. But that's the best I know